# MSSQL get messages

Tags: sql-server, go

I need to execute an sql backup script which displays progress in the form of messages.

```
query = 'BACKUP DATABASE [Mydatabase] TO  DISK = 'd:\Backup\mps.bak' WITH  RETAINDAYS = 30, FORMAT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10, CHECKSUM'
```

Here is the screenshot of the message:

[image]

```
row, err := conn.Exec(query)
rowsting, _ := row.RowsAffected()
fmt.Printf("Rows affected(%v)\n", rowsting)
panicOnError(err)
```

But only that I can get from messages is RowsAffected.

How can I get other events from messages?

Comment: Which library are you using? The generic `sql` library may not offer any way to return messages. The `Result` type returns values that are *not* generated in the same way across products, or even from one table to another (for `LastInsertId`)

Comment: It looks like you're using [go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)... have you tried adding 2 (log messages) to the `log` flags in your connection parameters?

Comment: You're right. I didn't see parameter about logging flags. Thank you very much.